# TestContainer Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, quarkus, testcontainers

according to https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#database-containers-launched-via-jdbc-url-scheme , i'm trying to create an Oracle Container with Quarkus using jdbc url scheme.
After provided a valid docker image ("store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1") and set this properties:

```
"%test":
  quarkus:
    datasource:
      jdbc:
        driver: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
        url: jdbc:tc:oracle:///databasename
      db-kind: other
```

i get this error:

```
Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:system/oracle@localhost:32827:xe)
2020-11-09 17:33:06,719 INFO  [ .2.0.1]] (Agroal_13889837441) Container store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 started in PT4M7.8483772S
2020-11-09 17:33:06,738 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (Agroal_13889837441) Datasource '<default>': Could not create new connection
2020-11-09 17:33:06,805 ERROR [io.qua.application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile test): org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Could not create new connection
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 0
Message    : Could not create new connection
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:65)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:80)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:453)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:158)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Flyway community editions (that ships with Quarkus) does not have support for Oracle. You need to use the Enterprise edition.

You need to replace the Quarkus Flyway dependency. Just exclude the one included and add the enterprise one (either in Maven or Gradle).

Comment: i saw that i didn't post the complete error:
in the error it says also:

`SQL State  : 66000
Error Code : 12505
Message    : Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Comment: That seems a problem connecting to the database. Are you able to connect to the database by any other means? With a SQL Client for instance?

Comment: @MattiaPoli I have the same message error how could you please solve it.? is is url correct `url: jdbc:tc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521///ORCL?TC_TMPFS=/testtmpfs:rw` ?